# Chrome "unable to load" an image as CSS 'background' - then it blames jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, laravel-4

**Hurr durr durrr disable adblock when working on sites that have ads. Bah.**

I have an image set through straight CSS as a background image on a div element. For some reason, the image (which is actually web accessible) isn't loading. Chrome dev tools show an error, but the error seems to blame jquery.

Failed 'GET' request

[image: failed 'Get' request]

Chrome blaming jquery

[image: chrome blaming jquery]

Basic CSS

[image: basic css]

Image is accessible by chrome

[image: image is accessible by chrome]

No CSS is overriding the image

[image: nothing overriding the image]

Chrome tools don't give me much - other images loaded in the exact same way, from the exact same place seem to load fine.

[image: other images loaded]

So I'm at a loss here. No idea why it's not showing up (ignore the '.dev' domain for the moment - it's just pointing to my local apache, and this same problem is showing up on the production site, too).

Although I don't think it's affecting it, I'm using Laravel 4 as a background PHP framework.

Comment: What other JavaScript are you importing?

Comment: Are you using any plugins or extensions that modify page content?

Comment: Bootstrap and a few plugins; my own application javascript. Disabling all javascript just makes chrome blame jquery 1.7.2... which also isn't imported anywhere.

Comment: Try turning off all your extensions (plug: there's an extension called  Disable Extensions Temporarily that makes this easy). If you're not loading jquery 1.7.2, it must be coming from one of them.

Comment: I'll bet it's something related to ad blocking.

Comment: Oh, ffs. Yeah, it was adblock plus. Thanks, Bramar.

Comment: Since you solved the issue please [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by turning off AdBlock Plus.

It is both a blessing and a curse.